# cURL to generate request not using an absolute URI when using `--proxy`

Tags: http, curl

When using `curl` to perform an HTTP request through a proxy, it seems to automatically use the absolute URI of the resource:

```
$ curl -v --proxy localhost:8080 localhost:8888/                                                                                                                                           
> GET http://localhost:8888/ HTTP/1.1                                                                                                                                                                                
> [...]
```

Because of the parsing behaviour of the proxy, I need the request to ask for the resource by just its path, like so:

```
$ curl -v --proxy localhost:8080 ???
> GET / HTTP/1.1                                                                                                                                                                                
> [...]
```

What `curl` options could trigger such request?

I've tried several combinations of using the `Host` header, and remove `localhost:8888` from the URL, without success.

Comment: The standards for HTTP/1.1 _require_ that requests to a proxy (except CONNECT and OPTIONS) use absoluteURI form, so I doubt there's a way to get curl to violate this. Plus it's not programming or development, which is now (for several years) the consensus scope of SO.

Comment: Ah, you are right as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-5.3.2 .

Comment: Should I delete my question? Or rather move it to a more appropriate platform (superuser sounds more adequate then)?

Comment: (IMO) it's ontopic for SU, though (as I said) I doubt they'll have a solution. webmasters.SX might also be suitable, but I am less familiar with that.